# Weakly contractible cover in étale homotopy theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-covers

It is easy enough to construct the separable closure $k^{sep}$ of a field $k$, which then has $\pi_0(k^{sep}) = 0$ (profinite set of connected components), $\pi_1(k^{sep}) = 0$ (there are no nontrivial finite étale extensions of $k^{sep}$).

Let $B$ be a connected scheme. How do I construct a smooth (or formally smooth) map $E \rightarrow B$ such that $E$ has weakly contractible étale homotopy type?

This would be like a universal cover, but for the higher étale homotopy groups.

Comment: What sort of an object are you expecting $E$ to be? In the topological setting already the $3$-connected cover of $S^3$ isn't a manifold (it's the string group $\text{String}(3)$) so I imagine it's too much to expect $E$ to be a scheme (as opposed to an ind-scheme or something stranger).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan. Could it still be a higher topos? My goal was to construct the loop space of a scheme by taking $E \times_B E$, but I did not foresee this problem.

Comment: Depending on what you want out of a loop space you can do the following instead. You can construct the based loop space $\Omega X$ of a based space from its free loop space $LX$ by fixing a point on the circle, considering the corresponding projection $LX \to X$, and taking a (homotopy) fiber. There's an analogous construction in AG: the (derived) free loop space $LX$ of a scheme (or stack, derived stack, etc.) is the (derived) fiber product $X \times_{X \times X} X$, where the two maps $X \to X \times X$ are both the diagonal $\Delta$. This is a global version of Hochschild homology.

Comment: Maybe you want a loop space that shifts all the etale homotopy up one degree though; I don't think this construction will have that property but I have no idea.

Comment: Thanks Qiaochu, you're a legend

Comment: You can take $E$ to be a separable closure of a generic point of $B$... But it is not possible to achieve this with $E\to B$ surjective.

Comment: @MarcHoyois. I guess that would be analogous to a map $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow S^3$ factoring through an inclusion $S^1 \rightarrow S^3$ through a covering $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow S^1$. Analogously, the map $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_p^{sep}) \rightarrow \text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ factors through $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_p) \rightarrow \text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ by a covering map $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_p^{sep}) \rightarrow \text{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_p)$. The relevant homotopy groups are the same in each example. In each case we lose track of $\pi_3$ of the base space.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I thought about your example with $\text{String}(3)$. There are, as you know, several cartesian closed categories that manifolds fit into, e.g. in synthetic differential geometry. Would $\text{String}(3)$ fit into such a category as that? If so, it might still be reasonable for a cover to fit into sheaves on some big site here.